# how to differentiate kernel logs and UI logs and rest of the logs based on the content in file

Tags: android

I am trying to write the perl script which will read the logs file and identify the file whether it is kernel logs, UI logs,Event Logs or Radio logs or Top logs.

Need some keywords to identify the logs.

Answer (score 0):

see the files in directory /dev/log, these four type logs are stored as four different files there.